# How to write the alert level to thecharacteristics of alert level in IOS 7?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am new to iOS development, and study about Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE, Bluetooth 4.0) for IOS.

I want to know how to use **`Immediate Alert Service`** on **`IOS 7`**.

I can **`scan , connect and discover the Service`** from the `BLE device`. 
The next is connect to the **`Immediate alert Service`** and write the **`characteristics of alert level`** to `BLE device`.

I have define the UUID of **`Immediate alert Service`** and **`Alert level`** like the following code.

```
#define IMMEDIATE_ALERT_UUID           @"00001802-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
#define ALERT_LEVEL_UUID    @"00002a06-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
```

The following code is about connect to the **`Immediate alert Service`**.

```
[peripheral discoverServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:IMMEDIATE_ALERT_UUID]]];
```

And the code about connect to the **`characteristics of alert level`** after connect to the **`IMMEDIATE_ALERT_UUID`** is like the following.

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error
{
    for (CBService *service in peripheral.services) {
        [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:ALERT_LEVEL_UUID]] forService:service];
    }
}
```

Subscribe to the **`characteristics of alert level`**.

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error
{
      if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:ALERT_LEVEL_UUID]]) {

            // If it is, subscribe to it
            [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
        }
}
```

But how to write the alert level to the **`characteristics of alert level`** ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `writeValue:forCharacteristic:type:`?

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error{
    if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:ALERT_LEVEL_UUID]]){

    uint8_t val = 0 //enter the value which you want to write.
    NSData* valData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(void*)&val length:sizeof(val)];

    [peripheral writeValue:valData forCharacteristic:characteristictype:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
}
```

Putting the parameter `CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse` will call `CBPeripheralDelegate` method
`- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didWriteValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error{
}`